# Motorcycle (MT-07) coolant temperature reducing to 60ºC when driving on highway

Tags: motorcycle, cooling-system, yamaha

On the last couple of days I have started noticing that whenever I ride at highway speeds (around 100 kph) the coolant temperature reduces to around 60ºC. If I ride slower it goes back to normal temperature (80ºC).

Normal behavior would be to stay at 80ºC and only get warmer if riding slower. Colder than 80ºC only when initially starting up the engine.

Is it a faulty thermostat that doesn't close? Could it be something worse?

Answer (score 0):

Typically defective or missing thermostat. A motor vehicle with OBD2 will usually set a P0128 for this.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal.

Think about how much more air your radiator is getting exposed to at highway speeds compared to regular speeds.

It's also winter time, so with the cooler ambient air temperatures, you combine that with faster air flow, that means more heat transfer.